# IE freezes during webpack $$_lazy_route_resource

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, webpack

I have a non-trivial Angular 7 web app compiled using ng build, it is about 4.7meg in DEV mode split across 6 chunks the largest is vendor at 3.1, followed by main at 1.1. It is about 3meg in production. 2.3 vendor, 0.3 main

I need it to work in IE 11. On initial page load it freezes for around 15s. By freezing I mean I get the blue circle indicator and if I click on the widow it goes pale and (not responding) appears in the title bar

Using the IE performance profiler, I can see that the vast majority of the time (13-14s) is HTML parsing and script evaluation of a script with the url

```
webpack:///frontend/$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object
```

the contents of which is

```
function webpackEmptyAsyncContext(req) {
    // Here Promise.resolve().then() is used instead of new Promise() to prevent
    // uncaught exception popping up in devtools
    return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
        var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
        e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
        throw e;
    });
}
webpackEmptyAsyncContext.keys = function() { return []; };
webpackEmptyAsyncContext.resolve = webpackEmptyAsyncContext;
module.exports = webpackEmptyAsyncContext;
webpackEmptyAsyncContext.id = "./frontend/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive";
```

note that "frontend" is the folder my app lives in, and I am not even using lazy loading.

Chrome doesn't freeze, it loads faster and doesn't seem to mention this url at all, instead spending most of its time in main.js as I would expect.

my angular.json

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "defaultProject": "portal",
    "projects": {
        "portal": {
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "frontend/app-ng",
            "projectType": "application",
            "prefix": "",
            "schematics": {},
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "frontend/public",
                        "index": "frontend/app-ng/app.html",
                        "main": "frontend/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "frontend/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "frontend/tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "frontend/app-ng/index.php",
                            "frontend/app-ng/favicon.ico",
                            "frontend/app-ng/env.js"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "frontend/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "frontend/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "frontend/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": true,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": true,
                            "buildOptimizer": true
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "portal:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "portal:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "portal:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "frontend/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "frontend/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "frontend/tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "frontend/karma.conf.js",
                        "styles": [
                            "frontend/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [],
                        "assets": []
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "frontend/tsconfig.app.json",
                            "frontend/tsconfig.spec.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "portal-e2e": {
            "root": "e2e/",
            "projectType": "application",
            "architect": {
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "portal:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "portal:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
            "styleext": "scss"
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that IE is likely going to be slower than more modern browsers, but freezing is bad User Experience and terrible first impression.

**UPDATE**

While working on a minimal complete example I discovered there was no call to `enableProdMode()`  so I fixed that, and the issue went away. So there seems to be something in the devmode code that IE doesn't like?

Comment: can you post the Enough code (include the webpack route configure) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT - I'll try to set one up, also what is a "webpack route configure"?